# list not appending values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code, I am passing dictionary to this function
This function uses `omdb` (https://github.com/dgilland/omdb.py) python module. The dictionary d2(key contain all movies title)
The values I get from `omdb`, I am trying to create a list which I utilize further in my code. For some reason its only appending the last values

```
def getdetails(d2):
    pprint.pprint(d2)
    for title_movies in d2.keys():
        #give list as output
        #pprint.pprint(title_movies)
        y=omdb.get(title=title_movies, timeout=5)
        movies_dataL=[]
        if 'title' in y:
            #pprint.pprint(y['imdb_rating'])
            movies_dataL.append(title_movies)
            movies_dataL.append(y['imdb_rating'])
        else:
            print('Movie not found')
            movies_dataL.append(title_movies)
            movies_dataL.append('No IMDB Info Available')
    pprint.pprint(movies_dataL)
    return movies_dataL
```

Here is how I call the function:

```
results=getdetails(movies_D)
pprint.pprint(results)
```

Here is the `movies_D` dictionary

```
movies_D={"Murder" : "rot,r", "Subedar Joginder Singh" : "grn,4", "Commando" : "blau,9", "Rambo":"gelb,20"}
```

Comment: Your code is not very easy to read. We could simplify it a lot!

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every loop iteration, you start with a clean list.  Move the initialization outside the loop:

```
movies_dataL=[]

for title_movies in d2.keys():
    #give list as output
    #pprint.pprint(title_movies)
    y=omdb.get(title=title_movies, timeout=5)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling for a while :)